# Scraping, My Query Parameters Are Wrong

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm on a website using Ruby and Mechanize to pass a POST query to a site.  The query that gets to the site, based on firebug, looks like this

```
param.PrdNo=-1&param.Type=Prop&param.RequestType=Normal&param.PropParams%5B0%5D.CrId=Base-MLB+Su+Washington+Na%40Atlanta+Brave
```

The QUERY I pass in my ruby code is this

```
QUERY = { "param.PrdNo" => "-1",
          "param.Type" => "Prop",
          "param.RequestType" => "Normal",
          "param.PropParams[0].CrId" => "Base-MLB+Su+Washington+Na@Atlanta+Brave"}

doc.agent.post(url, QUERY, content_type)
```

The logger prints out the following

```
D, [2014-08-10T14:46:24.844744 #15801] DEBUG -- : query: "param.PrdNo=-1&param.Type=Prop&param.RequestType=Normal&param.PropParams%5B0%5D.CrId=Base-MLB%2BSu%2BWashington%2BNa%40Atlanta%2BBrave"
```

How do I get my code to make a query that looks like the query from firebug?

Comment: have you tried `QUERY.to_json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post the string:

```
vars = "param.PrdNo=-1&param.Type=Prop&param.RequestType=Normal&param.PropParams%5B0%5D.CrId=Base-MLB+Su+Washington+Na%40Atlanta+Brave"
doc.agent.post url, vars, content_type
```

It will get sent as the raw post body.